# FuseIT WSDL2Apex Error: Missing namespace for operation

Tags: apex, soap-api, integration, soap, wsdl2apex

I'm stuck with generating apex classes from this WSDL. Is there a way to solve the missing namespace error? Is there an alternative way to generate apex classes from WSDL? Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="COINSInterface">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Header">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UserID" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="From" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="HostName" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Environment" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Created" type="xs:dateTime" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Version" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Login">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AuthToken" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="User" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Password" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CID" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Group" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="extUser" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="extAuth" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="confirm" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="yes" />
            <xs:enumeration value="y" />
            <xs:enumeration value="true" />
            <xs:enumeration value="no" />
            <xs:enumeration value="n" />
            <xs:enumeration value="false" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="action" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="CREATE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DELETE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="UPDATE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="PUBLISH" />
            <xs:enumeration value="ACKNOWLEDGE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="EXCEPTION" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="entity" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="arguments" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="ackID" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute name="testMsg" type="xs:boolean" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Body">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="vp_siteRow">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="externalID" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="job_num" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="jph_phase" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="hfc_code" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="updateForecast" type="xs:boolean" />
              <xs:element name="updateActual" type="xs:boolean" />

           <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="vp_wbsdefRow">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element name="externalID" type="xs:string" />
                     <xs:element name="vwb_code" type="xs:string" />

           <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="hs_stageRow">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="externalID" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="hss_stage" type="xs:string" />
                 <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="hfc_forecast" type="xs:date" />
                 <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="hfc_actual" type="xs:date" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="hfc_start" type="xs:date" />
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="hfc_progress" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
                         </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>

                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="COINSInterfaceResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Header">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UserID" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="From" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="HostName" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Environment" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Created" type="xs:dateTime" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Version" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SchemaVersion" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Object" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="confirm" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="yes" />
            <xs:enumeration value="y" />
            <xs:enumeration value="true" />
            <xs:enumeration value="no" />
            <xs:enumeration value="n" />
            <xs:enumeration value="false" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="action" use="optional">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="CREATE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DELETE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="UPDATE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="PUBLISH" />
            <xs:enumeration value="ACKNOWLEDGE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="RESPONSE" />
            <xs:enumeration value="EXCEPTION" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
      <xs:attribute name="entity" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
      <xs:attribute name="ackID" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute name="initialise" type="xs:boolean" use="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute name="initCount" type="xs:int" use="optional"/>
      <xs:attribute name="sin_ref" type="xs:int" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Body">
<xs:complexType>
 <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Exception">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Exception" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="ThrownAt" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="doAction">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="COINSInterface"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="doActionResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="COINSInterfaceResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="COINSInterfacePort">
<wsdl:operation name="doAction">
<wsdl:input message="doAction"/>
<wsdl:output message="doActionResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="COINSInterfaceBinding" type="COINSInterfacePort">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="doAction">
<soap:operation soapAction="https://henleyis.coinscloud.com/env/oademo/wouesb.p?service=HSESB034&amp;namespace=true" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="Service">
<wsdl:port name="COINSInterface" binding="COINSInterfaceBinding">
<soap:address location="https://henleyis.coinscloud.com/env/oademo/wouesb.p?service=HSESB034&amp;namespace=true"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Is there a WSDL definition with namespace included you can ask from your source? Also check out supported [definitions.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm)This error is not by the SOAP version, so you can rule that out.

Comment: In your WSDL file, 'targetNamespace 'is missing. TargetNamespace is attribute of 
<wsdl:definitions> and <xs:schema>
The target namespace would be the one where request will go to from Salesforce.
If you know the target namespace add this directly

Comment: @AtlasCan I was able to get a definition with the namespace provided, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried to process the WSDL you provided. The error was:

> Missing namespace for operation: [doAction] PortType:COINSInterfacePort
>   Parameter name: Input.Message.Namespace

This corresponds to this portion of the WSDL:

```
<wsdl:portType name="COINSInterfacePort">
    <wsdl:operation name="doAction">
        <wsdl:input message="doAction"/>
        <wsdl:output message="doActionResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

In particular, this element:

```
<wsdl:input message="doAction"/>
```

Notice that it is just a name with no namespace defined? If it had the namespace defined it would appear more like:

```
<wsdl:input message="somenamespace:doAction"/>
```

For that to work you would need to add a `targetNamespace` attribute to the `wsdl:definitions` element and the `xs:schema` as well.

The other challenge with this WSDL is the nested complex types that are defined in the schema. You will likely need to split (unnest) these out into distinct elements.

E.g. `COINSInterface` would be come something like:

```
        <xs:element name="COINSInterface">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Header" type="tns:Header" nillable="true" />
                    <xs:element name="Body" type="tns:Body" nillable="true" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Header">
          <!-- Elements nested under header are now hear. -->
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Body">
          <!-- Elements nested under body are now hear. -->
        </xs:element>
```

**But** you are going to need to drill all the way down through all the various types.

Comment: thank you for the help and the SFDC explorer :)